# Show that if $A, B,$ and $C$ are sets such that $|A|\le|B|$ and $|B|\le|C|$, then $|A|\le|C|$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

How would you prove this without using the law of transitivity?

Comment: What is $|A|$? Cardinality? If yes, what does this have to do with boolean algebras?

Comment: I like how three identical answers to this problem were posted in the span of a minute, lol...

Answer (score 6):

$|A| \leq |B|$ it means that there exist a injective function $f:A \to B$

$|B| \leq |C|$ it means that there exist a injective function $g:B \to C$

Then if you take $g \circ f:A \to C$ is an injective function, so $|A| \leq |C|$

Answer (score 4):

If $|A|\leqslant |B|$ then there exists an injection $f:A\to B$. If $|B|\leqslant |C|$, there exists an injection $g:B\to C$. Hence $g\circ f:A\to C$ is an injection from $A$ to $C$, which proves that $|A|\leqslant |C|$.

Answer (score 3):

If $g$ is an injective map from $A$ to $B$, and $h:B\to C$ is injective, then $f=h\circ g:A\to C$ is injective.